# UITableView header will not stick to the top of UITableView

Tags: uitableview, header, scroll

I have a UIViewController in my Storyboard and in that I have a UIView which contains a UITableView.

I added another small UIView into the top of the UITableView which contains some buttons and text.

Basically, when the run the app, the UIView which I have placed in the UITableView goes to the bottom of the UITableView for some reason.... It scrolls perfectly with the UITableView, but it stays at the bottom...

How can I get the inserted UIView to stay at the top of my UITableView and still scroll with the UITableView?

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is the table view header. You don't add it to the table directly, but rather, you assign it to the table's `tableHeaderView` property like this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myHeaderView;
```

Or you can just drag and drop a view into the storyboard at the top of the table view above the first section.

Comment: Thank you Timothy. This worked perfectly. However, I did actually drag my view into my tableview in my storyboard via Interface Builder but it still made the view go to the bottom of the TableView.